# Pandas get row number of dataframe with composite index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a directory with .csv files holding 60 min bars of stock data, and a Python script working to load them all into a pandas data frame, and index on the symbol and datetime, as below;

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

allFiles = glob.glob("D:\\Data\\60 Min Bar Stocks\\*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)

frame.set_index(['Symbol','Date'],inplace=True)

print(frame.loc["AAL", :])
print(frame.loc["AAL", :].loc["05-Jun-2017 09:00", :])
```

The first print brings back the following;

```
                   Open   High    Low   Close   Volume
Date                                                  
05-Jun-2017 09:00  49.53  49.88  49.40  49.64   560155

05-Jun-2017 10:00  49.58  49.89  49.58  49.85   575165
```

The second print brings back the following;

```
Open          49.53
High          49.88
Low           49.40
Close         49.64
Volume    560155.00
Name: 05-Jun-2017 09:00, dtype: float64
```

How can I find the row index for this individual row within the data frame, and then get a slice that would be the 12 rows consisting of the previous row, the current row, and the next 10 rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `MultiIndex` and then select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = '05-Jun-2017 09:00'
s = 'AAL'

pos = df.index.get_loc((s,d))
df1 = df.iloc[pos-1:pos + 11]
print (df1)
```

But there is problem if `t` is first value or some of `10` last:

```
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+11,len(df.index))]
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
                            Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Symbol Date                                                     
AAL    05-Jun-2017 08:00  1.1801  1.1819  1.1801  1.1817       4
       05-Jun-2017 09:00  1.1817  1.1818  1.1804  1.1814      18
       05-Jun-2017 10:00  1.1817  1.1817  1.1802  1.1806      12
       05-Jun-2017 11:00  1.1807  1.1815  1.1795  1.1808      26
       05-Jun-2017 12:00  1.1803  1.1806  1.1790  1.1806       4
       05-Jun-2017 13:00  1.1801  1.1801  1.1779  1.1786      23
       05-Jun-2017 14:00  1.1795  1.1801  1.1776  1.1788      28
       05-Jun-2017 15:00  1.1793  1.1795  1.1782  1.1789      10
       05-Jun-2017 16:00  1.1780  1.1792  1.1776  1.1792      12
       05-Jun-2017 17:00  1.1788  1.1792  1.1788  1.1791       4
```

---

```
d = '05-Jun-2017 09:00'
s = 'AAL'

pos = df.index.get_loc((s,d))
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+10,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                            Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Symbol Date                                                     
AAL    05-Jun-2017 08:00  1.1801  1.1819  1.1801  1.1817       4
       05-Jun-2017 09:00  1.1817  1.1818  1.1804  1.1814      18
       05-Jun-2017 10:00  1.1817  1.1817  1.1802  1.1806      12
       05-Jun-2017 11:00  1.1807  1.1815  1.1795  1.1808      26
       05-Jun-2017 12:00  1.1803  1.1806  1.1790  1.1806       4
       05-Jun-2017 13:00  1.1801  1.1801  1.1779  1.1786      23
       05-Jun-2017 14:00  1.1795  1.1801  1.1776  1.1788      28
       05-Jun-2017 15:00  1.1793  1.1795  1.1782  1.1789      10
       05-Jun-2017 16:00  1.1780  1.1792  1.1776  1.1792      12
       05-Jun-2017 17:00  1.1788  1.1792  1.1788  1.1791       4
```

Not possible select previousrow, because timestamp `t` is first value if index:

```
d = '05-Jun-2017 08:00'
s = 'AAL'

pos = df.index.get_loc((s,d))
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+10,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                            Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Symbol Date                                                     
AAL    05-Jun-2017 08:00  1.1801  1.1819  1.1801  1.1817       4
       05-Jun-2017 09:00  1.1817  1.1818  1.1804  1.1814      18
       05-Jun-2017 10:00  1.1817  1.1817  1.1802  1.1806      12
       05-Jun-2017 11:00  1.1807  1.1815  1.1795  1.1808      26
       05-Jun-2017 12:00  1.1803  1.1806  1.1790  1.1806       4
       05-Jun-2017 13:00  1.1801  1.1801  1.1779  1.1786      23
       05-Jun-2017 14:00  1.1795  1.1801  1.1776  1.1788      28
       05-Jun-2017 15:00  1.1793  1.1795  1.1782  1.1789      10
       05-Jun-2017 16:00  1.1780  1.1792  1.1776  1.1792      12
       05-Jun-2017 17:00  1.1788  1.1792  1.1788  1.1791       4
```

Not possible select all 10 next row, because `t` is `3.rd` value from back:

```
d = '05-Jun-2017 15:00'
s = 'AAL'

pos = df.index.get_loc((s,d))
df1 = df.iloc[max(pos-1,0): min(pos+10,len(df.index))]
print (df1)
                            Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
Symbol Date                                                     
AAL    05-Jun-2017 14:00  1.1795  1.1801  1.1776  1.1788      28
       05-Jun-2017 15:00  1.1793  1.1795  1.1782  1.1789      10
       05-Jun-2017 16:00  1.1780  1.1792  1.1776  1.1792      12
       05-Jun-2017 17:00  1.1788  1.1792  1.1788  1.1791       4
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is working, but there is one small problem, which I believe is related to the overall sort order of the data frame.  The last Symbol in the file is ZION, and the Symbol after "AAL" is "AAPL", so when I use your solution what I am actually getting is the last entry for ZION on 06-Jun-2017, the 8 entries for AAL on 07-Jun-2017 and then the first 3 entries for AAPL on 07-Jun-2017... how can I order it by Symbol then Date, so that this slice only returns rows for AAL?

Comment: Got it!  I added the following line and now it's working; frame.sort_index(inplace=True)